# Android link to another application

Tags: android, google-play

Could I in the application do link to another application in Google Play?

Is it allowed to this by the rules Google Play?

Could you help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.package.name"));

startActivity(goToMarket);
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it allowed to this by the rules Google Play?